# Event handler for all templates?

Tags: meteor

I would like to install a event handler to handle all `<a class="nav" />` links. Currently I am providing the same entry for event maps in almost every template. So I get entries like

```
Template.XXX.events = { 
  'click a.nav'          : linkCallback
}
```

all over the place. Is there a way to install event handlers globally? I couldn't find a way when [looking at the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps), but [tmeasdays meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) seems to be able to do it. I just cant figure out how.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just make a template that wraps every other template and attach the events to it:

```
<body>
  {{> body}}
</body>

<template name="body">
</template>

Template.body.events = function() {
  'click .nav': linkCallback
}
```

Comment: Sweet, as events are bubbled up this even allows more specific templates to have precedence. Thanks!